# Don't delete object of destination if it is in another Source in Coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, entity-relationship, cascade

I have a many to many relationship where `entity` are `Employee` and `Department`. Everything is going good but when i am trying to learn the relationship delete rules,i couldnot find out the right way.

I want to remove all the employee of the department if Entity Department gets deleted.But not those employee who are in another deparment.

> Cascade Delete the objects at the destination of the relationship. For
>   example, if you delete a department, fire all the employees in that
>   department at the same time.

But i dont want to remove the employee if they are already in another department.One teacher teaching `Swift`may be in many departments "Computer","Electrical","Civil".How can i acheive that..Tried to use cascade but that removes all the Employees which i have set destination as below:
[image][image]

**EDIT:** Tried using nullify but deleting Source causes the deletion of all related Destination. However, deleting any single one Source simply causes Destination to forget about that particular Source.I gues,I need something intermediate nullify and cascade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of mine i should not set the delete relationship to Cascade.But instead make both delete rule to nullify.And Check as in

```
class Departments: NSManagedObject {

// Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass
    override func prepareForDeletion() {
        for teacher in self.teachers!{ 
            if let tempTeach = teacher as? Teachers{  
                if tempTeach.departments?.count == 1{
                    self.managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(tempTeach)  
                }else{
                    print("this teacher is assigned to another department also so dont delete it") 
                }
            }
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following relationships will do what you want I think (I don't have the ability to test the answer here, but don't have rights to just leave a comment so you get the suggestion as an answer)

Employee -> Department Deny (can't fire an employee that is still assigned to a department).

Department -> Employee Cascade (fire all employees you can fire when the department is deleted, ie no longer has a department).

But it seems more reasonable to me set Department -> Employee to Nullify, and then make a separate scan for unassigned employees to fire outside the delete department code. This would also support general maintenance checks for employees that have had all their assignments removed.

Comment: Deny means you are not allowed to delete when there still exist a connection. So you can expect 1 delete to fail per Employee in the deleted Department that is still assigned to other departments.

Comment: after hours of research i found the same logic on SO and as i said it is a cool way to think but not the exact soution